# Django: Strange behaviour: whenever a datetime object is passed it is stored as tuple. Not happens always

Tags: django

I am experiencing a strange behaviour in my views.py file:

in my user model i have

```
date_something = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

The below is the code related in views.py

```
match = User.objects.get(email='test@test.com')
time_now = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone("UTC"))
match.date_something = time_now,
match.date_something2 = time_now,
# just want to check whats is stored from above line
check = match.date_something
locals()['check']
```

output: in the runserver console

```
(datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 10, 8, 20, 10, 787399, tzinfo=<UTC>),)
```

So here we see that the  `check` is a `tuple`.

Because of this when i am trying to save the model

```
match.save()
```

it says  `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

I checked this code in dango `Shell_plus` and it gives the right results.

```
In [2]: import datetime 
   ...: import pytz 
   ...:  
   ...: match = User.objects.get(email='test@test.com') 
   ...: match.date_something = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone("UTC")) 
   ...: check = match.date_something 
   ...:  
   ...: locals()['check']                                                                                                                                                             
Out[2]: datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 10, 8, 25, 59, 533597, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

**FOUND THE PROBLEM**

I was adding a comma at the end of that line in the views.py that's why it saving as a tuple.

```
match.date_something = time_now,
```

Comment: Please show real code (what is that `or` supposed to be?) and the full traceback.

Comment: you added comma in `models.py` not views.py?

Comment: check the edited

Comment: i added comma `match.date_something = time_now,`